# mule anypoint studio update site error

Tags: mule

**I have 64 bit system windows + java 8(64 bit version)  . I download mule anypoint 64 bit version**

I just want to install new softwrae connectors  .It shows below error message

1. **could not find

   http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0
          org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.provisionexception**

Answer (score 0):

It works on Mac, But it could be this issue on 64 bit Windows.

Try starting Eclipse with -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/

Comment: the same error .I tried above solution in mule anypoint stdio

Answer (score 0):

I hope issue has been solved but if not then Try using below link :
Anypoint Connectors Update Site - https://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks